# Program does not end as expected

Tags: python

Below code continues to print out `You Win!` even though the `computer_card`  is higher.

```
import random

computer_card = random.choice([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
player_card = raw_input('Please pick a card \n')

if player_card == 'Jack' or player_card == 'jack':
    player_card = 11

if player_card == 'Queen' or player_card == 'queen':
    player_card = 12

if player_card == 'King' or player_card == 'king':
    player_card = 13

if player_card == 'Ace' or player_card == 'ace':
    player_card = 14

if  computer_card == player_card:
    print 'Computer Choice: ', computer_card
    print 'Player Choice: ', player_card
    print 'Tie!'

elif computer_card > player_card:
    print 'Computer Choice: ', computer_card
    print 'Player Choice: ', player_card
    print 'Computer Wins!'

elif computer_card < player_card:
    print 'Computer Choice: ', computer_card
    print 'Player Choice: ', player_card
    print 'You Win!'

else:
    print 'I am not sure what is really going on if you got to this line.'
```

Comment: Typical problem: comparing strings with integers. This is probably Python-2.x?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is Python-2.7 and when you say comparing strings with integers...do you mean this? player_card = int(raw_input('Please pick a card \n'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

The input read by raw_string() is converted to string. So the line,

`player_card=raw_input()`

reads the input, convert it to a string and put it in player_card. And `'1' > 9`

**One Possible Fix:**

Change the comparison flow and convert the input to int if the input is not ['jack', 'queen', 'king' or 'ace']

```
if player_card == 'Jack' or player_card == 'jack':
    player_card = 11

elif player_card == 'Queen' or player_card == 'queen':
    player_card = 12

elif player_card == 'King' or player_card == 'king':
    player_card = 13

elif player_card == 'Ace' or player_card == 'ace':
    player_card = 14
else:
    player_card = int(player_card)
```

**Further Improvement:** Although this solution should fix the immediate problem, the code can be heavily improved. Some improvement suggestions,

1. Ensure your code can handle invalid input from user [never trust
       user input]
2. Use a dict or list to convert user input to a numeric
       value instead of handling cases one by one.

Comment: This will fail if the user gives a wrong input like a string for example. I think the OP need to rewrite his entire code. Otherwise +1. This solution will fix the immediate problem.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: Agreed. This was more to fix the immediate problem instead of giving a perfect solution. I think we can leave that as a homework ;-)

Comment: Yes of course. If you want you can edit your answer and mention it :-) It will be helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` puts a string into the variable `player_card`. When the player chooses King, Queen, Ace, Jack, the value of `player_card` is changed to int by the `if` statements. But if the `player_card` is something other than these, the value in `player_card` remains a string. [Like @Fallen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42240613/68587), this can be fixed by converting `player_card` to int.

Comment: Why repeat the other answers?

Comment: I just felt the answer needs to explain why it is going wrong along with where it is going wrong :)